# GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener and GestureDetectorCompat don't work. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gestures

I'm following [Detecting common gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) guide. I have linked to `android-support-v4.jar` library to get `GestureDetectorCompat`, and my code seems exactly the same as in the guide, except I'm detecting gestures in my custom view rather than in activity:

```
public class MyGlView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private GestureDetectorCompat m_gestureDetector = null;

    public MyGlView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public MyGlView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context) {
        if (m_gestureDetector == null)
            m_gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new MyGestureListener());

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(new DrawSurfRenderer());
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY); 
    }

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        m_gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);      
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            Log.e("", "OnScroll: deltaX=" + String.valueOf(e2.getX() - e1.getX()) + ", deltaY=" + String.valueOf(e2.getY() - e1.getY()));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.e("", "onSingleTapUp: X=" + String.valueOf(e.getX()) + ", Y=" + String.valueOf(e.getY()));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
        {
            Log.e("", "onLongPress: X=" + String.valueOf(e.getX()) + ", Y=" + String.valueOf(e.getY()));
        }
    }
```

No matter what I do with the touchscreen, I'm only getting `onLongPress`. In fact, when I do fast tap (quickly touching and releasing the screen) I still get `onLongPress` slightly after I remove my finger from the screen ( suspect that's a long tap detection delay).

What's the catch?

Comment: did you try to change `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` to `return false;`? And try yours actions on the Simple View (such as WebView like example).

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder: `return false;` doesn't change anything.

Comment: After some investigation i think you can try to add `onDown` method which returns true to your `onTouchEvent` method.

Comment: You will give always `onLongPress` because `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` never processed\accesed on your gestureDetector. You always will give `ACTION_UP`. Why no ACTION_MOVE? Because in Android Action_Move precessed after he give Action_UP. So gesture detector will be processed your actions like a long press.

Comment: @R.id.pandacoder: thank you! It seems silly that there is no default implementation, or that `onDown` is not abstract...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I quote [Android Guide on Detecting Common Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html):

> Whether or not you use GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, it's best practice to implement an onDown() method that returns true. This is because all gestures begin with an onDown() message. If you return false from onDown(), as GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener does by default, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the gesture, and the other methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener never get called. This has the potential to cause unexpected problems in your app. The only time you should return false from onDown() is if you truly want to ignore an entire gesture.

The fact that you did not implement the `onDown()` method was causing side effects.

Comment: Weirdly enough I had the same problem as the OP, except that my onLongPress Method was called just fine, despite not having onDown return true