# GestureDetector not registering double taps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gesture

I am having trouble implementing a `touchListener` to my `recyclerview` items that listens for Single taps and double taps.

Here is my code:

```
    val gDetector = GestureDetector(root.context, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Double tapped")
                    return super.onDoubleTap(e)
                }

                override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Show Press")
                    super.onShowPress(e)
                }

                override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Single tap up")
                    return super.onSingleTapUp(e)
                }

                override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Double tapped event")
                    return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e)
                }

                override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    Log.i(TAG,"single tap confirmed")
                    return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e)
                }
                override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Long press")
                    super.onLongPress(e)
                }
            })
            root.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
                gDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
```

I am using `GestureDetector` with `onTouchListener` but only `onShowPress` and `onLongPress` get called when I test it out. `onLongPress` gets called even when I do a quick tap on an item... `onShowPress` gets called everytime I tap no matter what.

[image]

I was unable to find examples online that combine both `GestureDetector` with `onTouchListener` on a view with Kotlin.

any ideas on how to get `onDoubleTap` and `onSingleTapConfirmed` to work?

**tried removing supers and returning true (this does not work)**
[image]

I am trying to implement 'GestureDetector.onDoubleTapListener' but I am getting this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try delete super methods. And return false where you don't need to register event.
Return true only where you need to register that event happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately what you suggested does not work. I added a screenshot so you can make sure I did what you asked properly

Comment: Check answer here, I think u need implement onDown() method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729007/gesturedetector-simpleongesturelistener-and-gesturedetectorcompat-dont-work-wh